# Fix MacBook display brightness

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

I'm looking for all the ways a macOS-user can be blocked from turning the screen brightness to maximum. I have this badly configured Mac from work I'm trying to fix.

Obviously in Preferences, the brightness of this MacBook Pro lid is turned up all the way. But it's totally not as bright as a normal MacBook...

Comment: Are you certain that the display brightness of the MacBook Pro is being capped? If so, hwo did you come to that conclusion? Is the MacBook you are comparing it with the same type and year?

Comment: Compared to the same MacBook of a colleague who's display much much brighter. I'm not really sure if it is capped or not, I do know there's a lot of other strange custom configuration done in the past that would make me indeed believe they capped it on purpose.

Comment: But perhaps something's wrong with the display...

Comment: Could it be a miscalibration? [This article explains where you can calibrate the display](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/calibrate-your-display-mchlp1109/10.14/mac/10.14).

Comment: Maybe you can check the brightness value stored in NVRAM? [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/199395/24324) explains how. Best would be if you could run the command on your and on your colleagues MacBook to compare the values.
If it turns out your value is lower, the answer also provides a command to increase the value.
If it turns out the values are the same, I would suspect a hardware issue on your mac.

Comment: my macbook returns `backlight-level %fe%03`
colleague macbook returns: `backlight-level c%07`
I don't know what that means though :)

Comment: Also tried Calibration Assistant, but "An error occurred" :(

Comment: The `backlight-level` values you get seem to be HEX values. `fe03` translates to `65027` and `c07` to `3079`. Are those the `backlight-level` values you get when the backlight is set to max on both machines? I would expect similar values, but [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/199395/24324) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46900173/1256347) I find different values for the maximum setting (but those might be different machines).   
Regarding the calibration assistant error, perhaps that is material for another question (I can't find much on it at the moment).

Comment: Also, to check the hardware you can try the [Apple Diagnosticst Tool](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731), but I'm not sure if it can detect a broken backlight.

Answer (score 0):

Try MonitorControl.

[Monitor Control - https://github.com/the0neyouseek/MonitorControl](https://github.com/the0neyouseek/MonitorControl)

I use it on a macmini, to control my external DELL monitor (via HDMI). I know it's not exactly the answer you wanted (mine being a desktop), but I did see this option - Change Brightness/Volume for all screens.

[Preferences - Display Settings -> Change Brightness on all screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRNXZ.png)

Comment: This isn't it, but still nice! I can use this at home to control my external display's brightness too, thanks!